# What is iOS mobile config equivalent in android?

Tags: android, configuration-files

In iOS we use mobile config to control various aspects of device such as

- VPN on
  demand
- Webclips
- Caldav
- carddav
- ldap
- restrictions
- VPN
- wifi
- Email
- exchange
  active sync
  etc.

We will host the config in a website upon downloading it the user will be asked for his permission then after installing all this aspects are controlled.If user want to roll back then he can go and uninstall the profile

I couldn't find any equivalent of that in android.

In iOS to configure these profile there is a tool also available called iPhone configuration utility.

If not what are the alternatives to achieve it in android.

Comment: sounds like you mean permissions in the manifest perhaps?

Comment: @tyczj - He means something like an auto-config script. I would suggest looking into how RFID (nfc) tags can be used to modify device settings.

Comment: The mobile config is a file that is made up of XML and its extension is .mobileconfig it is used to configure a device

Comment: We can configure any or many of what I listed above the profile can be sent to user via mail or can be hosted on web server when user taps on it it gets installed and device will work with respect to configuration profiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like mobileconfig is available in Android till now.

Note:

But there are OVPN files available for initiating OpenVPN connection in android device.

[Reference](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/54629/68069)