# Install wifi list onto an android device

Tags: android

I want to implement in a personal project a button for people to download my house's wifi onto their mobile phones. I know how to do it in iOS devices, using .mobileconfig files, but I don't actually know if it's possible to do the same for android devices, and install it without having any app, just from my internet site.

Sorry if I've not explained myself correctly but I'm not english. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is iOS mobile config equivalent in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998870/what-is-ios-mobile-config-equivalent-in-android)

Comment: I only need wifi config not all .mobileconfig stuff, and that question is almost three years old, it might have changed

Comment: If you search on Google you will find tons of that there is nothing similar. [For example this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41738574/5372008)